# Zeppelin: Problems while creating mysql interpreter on Google cloud

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cluster-computing, google-cloud-platform, apache-zeppelin

I was trying to create mysql interpreter using the reference document: https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.6.2/interpreter/jdbc.html

[image: creating mysql interpreter]
I press **Save** button at the bottom-left corner in the interpreter setting page. Without success. An error dialog on the screen was not.

### After saving I see it:

[image: After saving]
mysql interpreter absent(((

[image: interpreter.json]
new data in file `/usr/lib/zeppelin/conf/interpreter.json`

**~$ ls  /usr/lib/zeppelin/local-repo/2C52SHC9R**

```
mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar
```

I attach the [zeppelin-root-cluster-1-m.log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4kv84he9a7g7h6u/zeppelin-root-cluster-1-m.log?dl=0) and
[zeppelin-root-cluster-1-m.out](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1ab6e4xqdsshn8m/zeppelin-root-cluster-1-m.out?dl=0)

### This is my configuration:

zeppelin v0.6.2

**~$ uname -a**

Linux cluster-1-m 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u2 (2016-10-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux

**~$ gcloud --version**

```
Google Cloud SDK 137.0.1
alpha 2016.12.08
beta 2016.12.08
bq 2.0.24
bq-nix 2.0.24
core 2016.12.08
core-nix 2016.12.08
gcloud 
gsutil 4.22
gsutil-nix 4.22
```

**~$ ls -l /usr/lib/zeppelin/bin**

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2983 Oct 12 08:46 common.cmd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4196 Oct 12 08:46 common.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1186 Oct 12 08:46 functions.cmd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4142 Oct 12 08:46 functions.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1701 Oct 12 08:46 install-interpreter.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5112 Oct 12 08:46 interpreter.cmd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6160 Oct 12 08:46 interpreter.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3137 Oct 12 08:46 zeppelin.cmd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6796 Nov 28 00:24 zeppelin-daemon.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2937 Oct 12 08:46 zeppelin.sh
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I tested 0.6.2 and it seems like a bug but solved in master of github.

Can you use the master Zeppelin of github?